# Warn against BOOL to ENUM conversion in XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, enums, xcode9

Previously I had a method that does some task which takes in a BOOL.

```
-(void)processUserBasedonStatus:(BOOL)newUser
```

I then defined an NS_ENUM to accept more states like this

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, Status)
{
    StatusNewUser=0,
    StatusCurrentUser,
    StatusOldUser,
    StatusOther
};
```

And updated the method to use the new ENUM param

```
-(void)processUserBasedonStatus:(Status)userStatus
```

Everything works well, except that Xcode didn't complain about some places where I forgot to update the calling method, i.e.

```
[self processUserBasedonStatus:YES];
[self processUserBasedonStatus:NO];
```

In this case, YES & NO will only map to the top 2 values of the ENUM. I experimented with the list of warnings in Xcode but nothing allows the compiler to bring up this warning.

Is there a way to enable the compiler to warn us about this type of behavior?

Comment: In Objective-C `NO` is defined as `0` and YES as `1`, so it's perfectly legal.

Comment: Hmm in XCode 9.0.1 I cannot reproduce this getting error `Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'Status' with an rvalue of type 'BOOL' (aka 'bool')`

Comment: @schmidt9, I just updated to 9.0.1 and I don't get this warning. I'm wondering if there is a warning enabled in your project settings that triggers this error ?

Comment: I did not change any default warning settings, accepted proposals of Xcode to upgrade project settings though, so it may be a flag for, look exactly project settings

Answer (score 1):

In (Objective-)C the types `_Bool`, `char`, `int`, `long` *et al* and their unsigned counterparts are all *integer types*. Types defined by `enum` are not distinct types *per se* but a collection of constants of their underlying integer type.

The Objective-C type `BOOL` is either a synonym (`typedef` or `#define`) for `_Bool` or one of the `char` types, depending on the version of the compiler.

Due to *integer promotions* and *integer conversions* many assignments between different integer types are automatic and silent. Even floating point types can get involved, e.g.:

```
bool b = true;
float f = b;
```

is perfectly legal and might well go uncommented by a compiler even as a warning.

Given all this the answer to your question:

> Is there a way to enable the compiler to warn us about this type of behaviour?

is currently it seems “no” – the code is perfectly legal in (Objective-)C. It is however *dubious* and could indicate an error and there is nothing stopping the compiler issuing a *warning* as it does for some other legal but dubious constructs. You could submit a report to Apple at bugreport.apple.com (you need an Apple ID to do this) suggesting they add such a warning.